# declaring a variable as instance variable before or after some operations

Tags: python-3.x

I got confusion in quite a few places about adding a variable to class definition. like:

```
class net:
  def __init__(self, a,b,c):
     self.a=b*3
     self.b=b
     # what if do like this?
  def __init__(self, a, b)
     
     self.b=b
     self.a=a*self.b
```

Answer (score 0):

See `def __init__()` is nothing but a constructor which assigns values to variables of that class.What you are do is the same like you are assigning value of b to class variable b, and you are assigning **a times class variable b* to a for that instance* instead you can also do `self.a=a*b` it would have given same answer.
Check the example-

```
    class Test2:
  def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.a=a
    self.b=b*self.a
    self.c=b*a
  def printf(self):
    print("Value of a is {} ,value of b is {} and value of c is {}".format(self.a,self.b,self.c))##c output would be same as b

f=Test2(3,3)
f.printf()
```

Output

```
Value of a is 3 ,value of b is 9 and value of c is 9
```

I hope I've made you understand